# Apache Tomcat 8 only renders blank in browser

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, java-8, tomcat8

I opened a Tomcat server and tried accessing localhost:8080 in the browser but all I see is blank. That also happens when I try to access something like localhost:8080/missing, that does not exist, so I would see 404. Another thing is that while Mozilla simply displays blank, Chrome gives this message: "This localhost page can’t be found". I do now know if it is related, but when I open the server, I get the following stack trace:

```
10-Jul-2017 11:45:06.353 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1129)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1871)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name UploaderForm
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMappingDecoded(StandardContext.java:3191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMappingDecoded(StandardContext.java:3182)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureContext(ContextConfig.java:1385)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1198)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:783)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5213)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 10 more

10-Jul-2017 11:45:06.354 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Error deploying web application directory G:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.45\webapps\ROOT
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:757)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1129)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1871)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I mention that I am using Java 8 and Tomcat 8.0.45, on Windows 10.

Comment: Add the _web.xml_ file.

Comment: Here: https://pastebin.com/BNCrNuv3

Comment: I see now, that UploaderForm should not be there

Comment: Yeah and UploaderForm only has a mapping, it's missing a `<servlet>` declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [Luciano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4397788/luciano-van-der-veekens), I managed to resolve it, so the problem was this entry in my web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>UploaderForm</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/UploaderForm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

It should not be there because UploaderForm is not a servlet, just an html form in the ROOT directory.
That is also specified in the 14th line of the stack trace:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name UploaderForm`